# Black-Scholes formula to price a call option under stochastic interest rates, getting the error 'numpy has no attribute r'

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the Black-Scholes formula to price a call option under stochastic interest rates. But it keeps giving me the error module ''numpy has no attribute r'' What am I doing wrong here? How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
def european_option(K=1, S0=1, T=100, sigma=1, r0=1, k=1, theta=1, sigma_r=0.5, rho=1, N=1000, N_steps=100):
   #Simulate an interest rate
    time_grid = np.linspace(0, T, N+1)
    r = np.full(N+1, np.nan)
    r[0] = r0
    for i in range(N):
        dt = T/N_steps
        w_r = np.random.normal()
        r[i+1] = r[i] + k * (theta - r[i]) * dt + sigma_r * np.r[i] * np.dt * w_r
     #Simulate a stock price
    S = np.full(N+1, np.nan)
    S[0] = S0
    for i in range(N):
        w_S = rho * w_r + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2) * np.random.normal()
        S[i+1] = r[i] + k * (theta - r[i]) * dt + sigma_r * np.r[i] * np.dt * w_S
    call=np.max(S-K,0)
    price = np.exp(-rT)*call
    return price
print(european_option())
```

Comment: `np.r[I]` This looks wrong to me. Try just `r[I]`. (I didn't run it, but just taking a guess here.)

Comment: And perhaps similarly with `np.dt`… maybe you just meant `dt`?